# Inserting Data to MongoDb using Nodejs

Tags: node.js, database, mongodb, rest

I have couple of objects inside my Mongodb in a collection example of an object is :

```
_id: xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
abcd:
    efgh: " "
```

where `abcd` is an object which contains array of `efgh`  and I want to push data inside the array `efgh` (which means add data into that particular _id and into  efgh when that `api` is triggered)

I wrote an api for that

```
app.put('/route/:id', function(req, res, next){
    //console.log(req.params.id)
    console.log(req);
    collection.findByIdAndUpdate({abcd:req.params.id}, req.body.abcd).then(function(collection){
        res.send(collection)
    })
})
```

but when I tried it in postman it didn't work can u please help me with this.

Comment: Please check condition { _id: "5db6b26730f133b65dbbe459" }

Comment: @MaheshBhatnagar I checked it but didn't work

Comment: {abcd:req.params.id}  wrong condition, Please tell what comes response?

Comment: @MaheshBhatnagar UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: CastError: Cast to ObjectId failed for value "{ abcd: '5db6b26730f133b65dbbe459' }" at path "_id" for model "collection"
    at new CastError

Comment: {_id:ObjectId("5db6b26730f133b65dbbe459") } use objectId keyword

Comment: can you share schema of collection?

Comment: It is not clear whether you use mongoose or the mongo driver. Which one do you use?

Answer (score 1):

Your second arguments must use `$set` and the first argument must match for the id:

```
collection
  .findByIdAndUpdate(req.params.id, {$set: { abcd: req.body.abcd })
  .then(function(collection) {
    res.send(collection);
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want yo push inside array, MongoDB provides $push or $addToSet.

```
collection.findByIdAndUpdate({_id :req.params.id}, {$addToSet: { "abcd.efgh": req.body.abcd.efgh } }).then(function(collection){
    res.send(collection)
});
```